# Can ASRock N68C-GS4FX Motherboard w/ AMD Phenom II X4 940 run DDR3 RAM?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard

I have recently upgraded my Motherboard and am now looking at RAM.
I have an ASRock N68C-GS4FX Motherboard and a AMD Phenom II X4 940 Processor. I have used the CrucialPC system scan application, and in the memory window it does suggest upgrading to DDR3 RAM (as it would fit in the Motherboard), but I was under the impression that my Processor would not work with DDR3 RAM.

Comment: [Yes;  You have two DD2 slots and two DDR3 slots per the manual.](http://download.asrock.com/manual/N68C-GS%20FX.pdf)

Comment: If the CPU is AM2+ it cannot run DDR3 RAM. Only AM3 socket CPU's will run DDR3 RAM.

Comment: I linked to the manual for a reason.  Why is this question getting upvoted consider it shows zero research effort?

Comment: It may not be as easy to find the information regarding the sockets and supported RAM types. The motherboard is confusing as it is a hybrid motherboard. I upvoted simply to remove the negative but now it has risen.

Comment: @Ramhound Your comment "Yes; You have two DDR2 slots and two DDR3 slots..." is misleading as the answer is *no*. The manual does answer the question at the very bottom of page 17, "DDR3 memory module is only supported by installing AM3/AM3+
CPU." but it's easy to miss that.

Comment: @MC10: Why do you upvote on your opinion on the downvotes, and not your opinion on the question?

Comment: @nallar - I disagree that my comment is misleading though.

Comment: @Ramhound: Your comment **is** misleading. Saying "Yes" when the answer is "No" is the definition of misleading.

Comment: @Will It seems the CPU is a dependency whether you can use DDR3 memory. You should edit your post to include what CPU you intend to use so the best answer can be given.

Comment: @Braiam Your edit removes crucial information - the answers depend on what processor is used, and you removed it. Please roll it back.

Comment: @mokubai if you are going to revert the edit, don't leave it as crappy as it was originally!

Comment: @nallar sorry, it wasn't intended. I knew that the graphics card wasn't related, but I somehow removed the cpu information along with it.

Answer (score 15):

That motherboard supports both AM2(+) and AM3(+) socket CPU's, hence the confusion. AM2 CPU's will *only* work with DDR2 RAM. AM3 CPU's, on the other hand, are *backwards compatible* and will work with DDR2 or DDR3 RAM. Thanks @**sunk818** for the clarification.

The **AMD Phenom II X4 940** is an AM2+ socket so it will *NOT* support DDR3 RAM. This is because you have a [hybrid motherboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_AM2%2B#Hybrid_motherboards).

Comment: Manual seems to state AM3 is backward compatible with DDR2: http://download.asrock.com/manual/N68C-GS%20FX.pdf

http://i.imgur.com/74ZCpRw.jpg

Comment: Ah yes, I will update that.

Answer (score 2):

The AM2+ Phenom 2 x4 940 does not support DDR3. Only the AM3 version Phenom 2s support both DDR2 and DDR3, because they have dual memory controllers built-in.